# How to replace mistakenly typed characters without pressing backspace?

Tags: windows-8, typing

I have seen this in many videos, where the programmers replace a mistakenly typed character without typing the backspace button. Here is a [sample video](https://youtu.be/l9UyIgfV8pc?t=1m47s) showing what I am actually meaning where the typer replaced C for his typo K when he was typing PACKAGE.

[image]

How to do this? What are the short keys?

Comment: Huh. I'd love to know this too. However this may be a feature of Visual Studio, in which case, I'd still love to know!

Comment: uh, it looks like he did hit backspace. he typed `paka` which changed to `pak`, then to `pac` then on to `package`. But in terms of autocorrect, Visual Studio has a great deal of typing-assistance that just isn't available in every program. programs like modern versions of Visual Studio or MS Word use very sophisticated analysis and correction routines that are very tightly tied to their specific functions and purposes. its pretty much like autocorrect on a smartphone; just better in most cases.

Comment: @FrankThomas He **didn't** backspace to `pa` before typing `pac`. It was `pak` then magically `pac`. I also think it might be a Visual Studio thing though.

Comment: I'm still not convinced, but if there is a shortcut key, it is tab. If I remember on Monday, i'll try it out.

Comment: BTW, How to do this in Visual Studio, PhpStorm, Notepad++ and Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>insert</kbd>

That makes you overwrite what's under the cursor in most applications. Hit insert again to undo.

Comment: I don't think this is it. The cursor was _after_ the `k` not before the `k`. If the cursor was before the `k` and "Insert" was on then yes this would happen but the fact the cursor was _after_ the `k` is why this is so confusing. Side note: the mouse cursor (not the blinking line indicator) wasn't even near the text, was down near the bottom right, also.